# VS 2010 unable to locate WP7 Resources

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-3.0, expression-blend, windows-phone-7

Lately I have installed Windows Phone 7 developement tools and noticed that VS2010 unable to resolve the phone resources like styles and fonts. But Blend does load them all, it's bit annoying that all time get exception message on designer.

Can anyone suggest the solution please?

Comment: I get the same thing (even after several reinstalls) I had assumed this was just a "feature" of it still being beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to repair or reinstall Visual Studio, Silverlight 4 and Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools? I don't think rebooting or reinstalling WP7DT will help in this case.